# ng-bootstrap datepicker year selection range

Tags: datepicker, selection, ng-bootstrap

The year selection shows always only 21 years, the current selected year, the ten years before and the ten years after.

[image]

Is it possible to change the number of years displayed?

For example, to always show the years from 1900 to 2100.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Working solution has been provided in the stackblitz cretaed by me:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-datepicker-popup-wtyhbv?file=app/datepicker-popup.ts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible though setting "minDate" and "maxDate" properties.

For example,

```
<input [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" ngbDatepicker #d="datePicker">
```

in component.ts

```
export class DatepickerComp {
   minDate = {year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1};
   maxDate = {year: 2100, month:1, day: 1};
}
```